# Where is WinAPI documentation?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, esent

E.g. I search “JetCommitTransaction”, search finds https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269191(v=exchg.10).aspx which redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/

That API is available in all versions of Windows starting from Win2000 to the very latest Win10, and even available for Windows 10 UWP apps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-esentdll so it’s not deprecated or something.

archive.org works but it's slow and inconvenient.

Comment: Enter "cache:URL" in google search box, there are also browser extensions if this is still too inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is moving all documentation from msdn.microsoft.com to learn.microsoft.com so I assume this will work itself out after a while but this is the first time I have seen a completely broken redirect.

I think Google cache and Archive.org are your best options for now. You could also try contacting [@docsmsft](https://twitter.com/docsmsft)/[Github issues](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues).

Comment: Right, redirects to a big white nothing. Very disappointing. Hope they’ll fix soon.

Comment: Not exactly the first time MSDN has broken links. Even though they use the stupid hash thing as the page id links still break after a couple of years. And, this is at least the fourth time they have moved: msdn. -> msdn2. -> msdn. -> docs.

Comment: "*this is the first time I have seen a completely broken redirect*" - I've seen several of them.

Answer (score 2):

We are working on moving all MSDN documentation to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com). Some of the redirects were accidentally deployed early - those have been rolled back, until the migration is complete. In the meantime, the documentation is accessible on MSDN on the links you specified above.